# Visual Studio 2019 .resources file naming

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, resources, visual-studio-2019

I have two almost identical code bases, one in VS 17 and one in VS 19. Each has a view with the same relative path inside the project which explicitly loads a widget from the view's .resources file using the ComponentResourceManager class.

For the sake of illustration, the paths of the views are as follows:

```
Old: A.B.C.View.cs
New: A.B.C.View.cs
```

The namespaces of the views:

```
Old: A.B
New: A.B
```

The names of the .resources files post-compile:

```
Old: A.B.View.resources
New: A.B.C.View.resources
```

I've searched the IDE, the project, and online and I can't find any reason why one loads according to the namespace and the other according to the path. I've had to get around this by hard-coding the correct name in the new codebase ResourceManager but I'd like to fix this properly. It should be named according to namespace, not the path.